# What is "__cdecl"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to use the AES algorithm with MPI.

I code in visual c++. When I compile the code I get this error:

> unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl BTM(int,int)" (?BTM@@YAXHH@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: It's having trouble linking to a library of sorts.

Comment: See [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 12):

[`__cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a calling convention, but the problem you have is a linker failure. It is stating that a definition for the function called `BTM()` cannot be located.

Ensure you are linking with all the necessary `.lib`s.

Comment: you're probably missing a lib file.

Comment: plz explain more. How to find it.

Comment: @ar.gorgin, is `BTM()` part of the `AES` library?

Comment: Yes, There is . void BTM(int low, int high);

Comment: @ar.gorgin, ok. I don't know what distribution of AES you have, but there should be a `aes.lib` file, or something similarly named. You need to add the `.lib` to your linker command. (I don't use IDEs so I cannot help there I am afraid).

Comment: In your Project Settings, choose 'Link' section and add 'aes' (or whatever the .lib file for AES library is called) to the list of libraries to link. You may need to help the linker find it by adding the path to the AES library in the Library Directories section. See the Visual C++ help for more info.